# Visualize the output of Vgg16 model by TSNE plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pytorch, scatter-plot

I need to visualize the output of Vgg16 model which classify 14 different classes. 
I load the trained model and I did replace the classifier layer with the identity() layer but it doesn't categorize the output.

Here is the snippet:
the number of samples here is 1000 images.

```
epoch = 800
PATH = 'vgg16_epoch{}.pth'.format(epoch)
checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
epoch = checkpoint['epoch']

class Identity(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Identity, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return x

model.classifier._modules['6'] = Identity()
model.eval()
logits_list = numpy.empty((0,4096))  
targets = []


with torch.no_grad():
    for step, (t_image, target, classess, image_path) in enumerate(test_loader):

        t_image = t_image.cuda()
        target = target.cuda()
        target = target.data.cpu().numpy()
        targets.append(target)

        logits = model(t_image)
        print(logits.shape)

        logits = logits.data.cpu().numpy()
        print(logits.shape)
        logits_list = numpy.append(logits_list, logits, axis=0)     
        print(logits_list.shape)


tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1, perplexity=10, n_iter=1000) 
tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(logits_list)   

 target_ids = range(len(targets))

plt.scatter(tsne_results[:,0],tsne_results[:,1],c = target_ids ,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("jet", 14))
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(14))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

here is what this script has been produced: I am not sure why I have all colors for each cluster! 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The VGG16 outputs over 25k features to the classifier. I believe it's too much to t-SNE. It's a good idea to include a new `nn.Linear` layer to reduce this number. So, t-SNE may work better. In addition, I'd recommend you two different ways to get the features from the model:

1. The best way to get it regardless of the model is by using the `register_forward_hook` method. You may find a notebook [here](https://github.com/Atcold/pytorch-CortexNet/blob/master/notebook/network_bisection.ipynb) with an example.
2. If you don't want to use the register, I'd suggest this one. After loading your model, you may use the following class to extract the features:

```
class FeatNet (nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vgg):
        super(FeatNet, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg.children())[:-1]))

    def forward(self, img):
        return self.features(img)
```

Now, you just need to call `FeatNet(img)` to get the features.

To include the feature reducer, as I suggested before, you need to retrain your model doing something like:

```
class FeatNet (nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vgg):
        super(FeatNet, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg.children())[:-1]))

    self.feat_reducer = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(25088, 1024),
        nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
        nn.ReLU()
    )
   
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(1024, 14)


    def forward(self, img):
        x = self.features(img)
        x_r = self.feat_reducer(x)
        return self.classifier(x_r)
```

Then, you can run your model returning `x_r`, that is, the reduced features. As I told you, 25k features are too much for t-SNE. Another method to reduce this number is by using PCA instead of `nn.Linear`. In this case, you send the 25k features to PCA and then train t-SNE using the PCA's output. I prefer using `nn.Linear`, but you need to test to check which one you get a better result.